# How to fix "Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed" exception?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a simple app which shows me a list of albums, and I'm struggling with the following code:

```
mmr.setDataSource(a.getSong(i).getPath());
```

This is the "buggy" part on a function that supposes to add a Bitmap image to the Bitmap value on the Song object (as shows bellow..)
Now for an unknown reason, when the file has no album art, I get (as said on the title) "Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed." exception.

Now I tried many different ways to add this Bitmap to the Song object - including using Glide, Media.Audio.Album.ALBUM_ART, and every other way I could find on the internet.

Currently, I'm using an approach that uses the decodeStream (from the BitmapFactory library)

```
    void setCover (int index){
        for (int i = 0; i < lstAlbums.get(index).getAmountOfTracks(); i++) {
            Album a = lstAlbums.get(index);
            MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            try {
                mmr.setDataSource(a.getSong(i).getPath());
                byte[] artBytes = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
                if (artBytes != null) {
                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(mmr.getEmbeddedPicture());
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    a.getSong(i).setCover(bm);
                } else {
                    //a.getSong(i).setCover(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_default_image));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

What I know is that when I call "mmr.getEmbeddedPicture()" for a song that has no cover I will get just simple "null" value.
I'm 100% sure that it has nothing to do with the value that "getPath()" returns because the function works perfectly when I have a song with album art.

Comment: I hope that everything is clear and I didn't miss anything... Tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it!
What was wrong was the path. Lol.
I completely changed the code.

I need it to be on CardView, so on the RecycleViewAdapter.java file I wrote the following code:

```
Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
/*getAlbumId gives you the ID of the album
*(provided by - long albumId = songCursor.getLong(songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
*/
Uri imgUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumList.get(position).getAlbumId());

Glide.with(mContext)
        .load(imgUri)
        .apply(requestOptions)
        .into(holder.img_album_cover);
```

on `onBindViewHolder()` void.

```
mContext is - Context mContext object //provided from RecyclerViewAdapter object)

requestOptions is - RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background); 
//Which is a part of the Glide library.

holder.img_album_cover //is - the ImageView in which I'm going to insert the image.
```

If somebody needs help, [this great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lq3Wvcy1kHo) helped me solve the problem.

Wish you luck! (I'm here if you need my advice...)